# Kendo calendar only for reading

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

in the project, I want to use a calendar that will only be informative. It will display color-coded days in which a reservation can be made and where a reservation has already been made.

But I need to do read-only chalices, without the possibility of date picking - so that it is not clickable.

```html
 @{ 
                var orderDateInfos = Model.CarOrders;
                List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
                foreach(var orderInfo in orderDateInfos)
                {
                    foreach(var ordersDate in orderInfo.OrderDays)
                    {
                        list.Add(ordersDate);
                    }
                }
            }
            @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
            .Name("availableCalendar")
            .Selectable("multiple")
            .SelectDates(list)
            .Value(Model.CarOrders.First().RentStartDate)
            )
```

[image: AvailableCalendar]

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see in kendo documentation it allows only to disable days not make readonly or disable the entire calendar. 
From the site http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/calendar/disable-dates I would probably try to return true (without any additional logic) to the function disableDates. 
This way all days will probably be disabled. 
However the selected dates this way wouldn't show as selected so you could add a css rule according to the aria-selected="true" which seems to be the indicator for the selected dates.

So step by step one possible solution could be:

Add a function to the disableDates attribute

```
.DisableDates("disableAllDates")
```

Set your function to return true in all cases

```
function disableAllDates(){
    return true;
}
```

And add some css for the td[aria-selected="true"]. For example

```
td[aria-selected="true"] {
    background: red;
}
```